# ScrollListener for RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, onscrolllistener

I am using `RecyclerView` inside `NestedScrollView`. For smooth scrolling

```
nestedScrollView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```

And this `RecyclerView` is dynamic, dynamically adding rows on the `scroll`. But scroll listener is not working `NestedScrollingEnabled` is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        scroller.setOnScrollChangeListener(new NestedScrollView.OnScrollChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChange(NestedScrollView v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY) {

                if (scrollY > oldScrollY) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scroll DOWN");
                }
                if (scrollY < oldScrollY) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Scroll UP");
                }

                if (scrollY == 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "TOP SCROLL");
                }

                if (scrollY == (v.getChildAt(0).getMeasuredHeight() - v.getMeasuredHeight())) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "BOTTOM SCROLL");
    f (viewGroup1.getChildAt(viewGroup1.getChildCount() - 1) instanceof RecyclerView){
//add code here }

                }
           }
        });
```

Comment: Valid only for API 23 and above.