# RecyclerView inside NestedScrollView does not retain recycler scroll position if rc view height is not given in dp

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black"
android:fillViewport="true"
tools:context=".Details_Act.About_Act">

<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/master_nest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<Some More Layouts>...</Some More Layouts>

 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                android:id="@+id/eps_rcview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/relative"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />

 </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In above case when i backpress from another activity recycler position is reset

But if i give recyclerview a height of any 400dp,500dp,etc... instead of fill parent or match parent it work it retain recycler position

Is there anyone who can help me

I know nestedscrollview take only one child , i am not going to give full code cuz it has too many lines

Comment: RecyclerView doesn't call scroll listener inside the nested scroll view. Remove recyclerview inside of nested scroll view

Comment: I can't, I need both Recycler and NestedView , is there another way to solve this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41735332/9523118 check this one it might help